# Sort By Grouping NumFound Field

Tags: solr, content-search, indexing

Hello **Sitecore Stack Exchange**,

Environments: Sitecore 9.2, Solr 7.5.0|SolrCloud 7.5.0, Custom search index.

In the Search logic I have the next requirement:
I should group search response and sort groups by **score** and by **numFound** group value then
[image: Solr Grouping Picture]

I saw some links that noticed that it is not possible or it is possible through two queries using facets (implemented currently). But they are pretty old and probably something changed.
For example:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457868/how-to-order-groups-by-count-in-solr
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219765/solr-6-how-to-group-by-title-and-return-groups-that-contain-minimum-5-numfound
3. [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9678?jql=text%20~%20%22numFound%22](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9678?jql=text%20%7E%20%22numFound%22)

Will be appreciate any help.

Comment: Check this article https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_5/result-grouping.html

Comment: @PeterProcházka how it can resolve my issue?